# How to deploy a .net webservice?

Tags: android, web-services

I have created a .net webservice.It is running in local host.I am using that webservice in my android application.But i am not getting the output.I wanted to ask that how can i make my webservice available over internet?

Comment: you need to publish your web-service on live port.

Comment: [Deploying web-service](http://en.csharp-online.net/Creating_ASP.NET_Web_Services%E2%80%94Deploying_a_Web_Service_Directly_to_IIS)

Comment: Q: Do you have an Internet provider?  Did they give you a domain name?  A server with a static IP address?  Is it a Windows server, running IIS? If so, you can deploy your web service to that server.  Otherwise, you have some "challenges" ;)